# jquery increment not working for appending form fields

Tags: jquery

I have the following code but the counter i specified as `cnt` is not working as i am adding more and more block of code, it is not increment the form names

here is my code

```
var cnt = 1;
    $(".addMore").click(function() {
            cnt++;
            $(".append-outer").append('<div class="append-inner">\
                <div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-8">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Company</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_company"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-4">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Phone</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_phone"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>\
                </div>\
                <div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-8">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Address</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_address"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-4">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>FAX</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_fax"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>\
                </div>\
                <div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-6">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Contact</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_contact"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="col-sm-6">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Account</label>\
                            <input type="text" name="form_account"'+cnt+'" class="form-control" _required="required">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>\
                </div>\
                    <button type="button" class="remove-append"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>\
                    </div>');

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code change `"'+cnt+` become `'+cnt+`.
It will work fine.

If you're familiar with ES6, using template string instead of. [Demo code is here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRqVNg)